# Eclipse RCP - Content Assist trouble

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to add content assist to my editor. I've added

```
    public IContentAssistant getContentAssistant(ISourceViewer sv) {
    ContentAssistant ca = new ContentAssistant();
    IContentAssistProcessor pr = new TagCompletionProcessor();
    ca.setContentAssistProcessor(pr, XMLPartitionScanner.XML_TAG);
    ca.setContentAssistProcessor(pr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
    return ca;
}
```

to editor configuration, then made completion processor class:

```
public class TagCompletionProcessor implements IContentAssistProcessor {
private ITypedRegion wordRegion;
private String currentWord;
private SmartTreeSet tags;
public TagCompletionProcessor() {
    tags = new SmartTreeSet();
    //filling tags skipped
}
@Override
public ICompletionProposal[] computeCompletionProposals(ITextViewer viewer,
        int offset) {
    System.out.println("compute");
    wordRegion = viewer.getDocument().getDocumentPartitioner().getPartition(offset);
    try {
        int offs = wordRegion.getOffset();
        int len = wordRegion.getLength();
        currentWord = viewer.getDocument().get(offs, len);
        return tags.getProposals(currentWord.toLowerCase(), offs, len);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
@Override
public IContextInformation[] computeContextInformation(ITextViewer viewer,
        int offset) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public char[] getCompletionProposalAutoActivationCharacters() {
    return new char[] {'<'};
}
@Override
public char[] getContextInformationAutoActivationCharacters() {
    return null;
}
@Override
public IContextInformationValidator getContextInformationValidator() {
    return null;
}
@Override
public String getErrorMessage() {
    return "No tags found";
}
```

}

... but it's not working. Init goes normal, but auto-activation does not working and when I'm pressing ctrl-space (I've added org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.contentAssist.proposals command to Bindings ext point) empty list appearing (also it's not near cursor, but in some constant place). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there was some null output in the middle. What a fail =(

Answer (score 0):

If your document implements *IDocumentExtension3*, than you have to set the partitioning of your assistant..

```
ca.setDocumentPartitioning(MyPartitionScanner.MyPartitioning);
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You should register your action in the editor and substitute the default one.
Here is the an example how to do it with Content Assist action.

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_actions.htm